# After adding Maven framework support in IntelliJ, it moved all /src/com/... files into /src/main/java/com/... without updating git history. How fix?

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea

I added Maven support to a project that previously did not have it. IntelliJ then moved all the java files, but even though it's a git project, did not use `git mv` and so there's no file history.

How do I fix this?

Example:

```
//The below structure was before Maven
/src
.../com
    .../test
        .../SomeClass.java

//After Maven
/src
.../main
    .../java
        .../com
            .../test
                .../SomeClass.java
```

Comment: @janos This appears to have worked! Can you please make this an answer so I can mark the question answered?

Comment: Sure, done, let's clean up the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renames are not first class citizens in Git.
Git detects renames based on file content changes.
As such, the main purpose of `git mv` is to simplify staging.
If files get renamed without `git mv`,
that causes only a minor inconvenience,
which you can rectify by appropriate `git add` commands.
That is, for each renamed file, one `git add` for the old name ("deleted file" from the perspective of Git), and one `git add` for the new name ("new file" from the perspective of Git).

In your particular example,
a simple fix could be staging everything by running `git add .` at the project root.
After that, check the output of `git status -sb`.
There's a good chance that Git will figure out all the renames.